# Update TextInput value of hash of array in onChangeText function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, textinput

```js
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
    this.state = {
     answers: props.element.answers_data.map((answer, index) => {
     return answer;
    }
  })

     <TextInput
      value = {this.state.answers[index].answer_text}
     onChangeText={(answer_text) => {
              this.setState({
                answers: [
                    ...this.state.answers.slice(0, index),
                    {answer: {answer_text}},
                    ...this.state.answers.slice(index + 1, 
                    this.state.answers.length)
                ]
              });
            }} 
       />
```

my answers data structure is **like= 0: {id: 799, answer_text: "helloas fast" percentage: 0}**

i want to update the answer text and store it in the this.state.answers, but when i write text on textinput and update it i am getting only answer_text in hash and i want all id, answer_text, percentage in hash.
So, please i need suggestion.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't handle your array data well. You can either keep its structure, or use `answers_data.map` to convert them into string.

**Full code of option one:**

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    answers: props.element.answers_data.map((answer, index) => {
      return { ...answer };
    })
  }
}

<TextInput
  value = {this.state.answers[index].answer_text}
  onChangeText={(answer_text) => {
          this.setState({
            answers: [
                ...this.state.answers.slice(0, index),
                { ...this.state.answers[index], answer_text },
                ...this.state.answers.slice(index + 1, this.state.answers.length)
            ]
          });
        }} 
 />
```

**Full Code of option two:**

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    answers: props.element.answers_data.map((answer, index) => {
      return answer.answer_text;
    })
  }
}

<TextInput
  value = {this.state.answers[index]}
  onChangeText={(answer_text) => {
          this.setState({
            answers: [
                ...this.state.answers.slice(0, index),
                answer_text,
                ...this.state.answers.slice(index + 1, this.state.answers.length)
            ]
          });
        }} 
 />
```

Comment: my answers structure is like this = 0: {id: 777, answer_text: "hello", percentage: 0}
2:{id: 776, answer_text: "gb", percentage: 0}
and when i am writing answer_text then it only gives me answer_text but i want this {id: 776, answer_text: "gb", percentage: 0} whole structure.              please suggest me what i can write there to get this 3 value in one object

Comment: modified my answer for two possibility to change your code. check which one is more readable to you. feel free to ask here.

Comment: thank you so much for your response @val.. its working